# Google Match Content Ad is moving trying to fit in big screen resolutions

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, adsense

We are having a couple of issues with Google matched content ads and Bootstrap 4.

1) The ad in big resolutions tries to "adapt" to the container, changing the size: https://gyazo.com/1f7f485f4a0dd91e33e69aaf41af2412

I've tried several ways like set a Fixed width, but still happening.

2) Is there a way to exclude the ads from subdomains? Examples:

- I want my domain us.domain.com to show only the articles of my US domain
- I want my domain ca.domain.com to show only the articles of my Canada domain

Click [here](https://www.mysavings.com/testad.asp) to go to the test page Ad

Answer (score 0):

As for question 2, I suggest using Javascript's HTML DOM capabilities to automatically search for ads from non-local domains, and using that try deleting those HTML elements.

*document.removeChild()* is what you will probably use for deleting the unnecessary ads. I suggest researching more on this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp).